# Error importing a custom class from a module in the current location

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file called `blogtag.py` as follows

```
from .base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, schema, Sequence, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .blogpost import Blogpost


class Tag(Base):
    """Tag model."""

    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    tag_id_seq = Sequence('tag_id_seq', metadata=Base.metadata)
    id = Column("id",Integer, tag_id_seq,server_default=tag_id_seq.next_value(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
    isactive = Column('isactive', Boolean)
    postList = relationship(Blogpost, secondary="posttag")
```

and another file in the same location , called `blogpost.py` which looks like this as follows

```
from .base import Base
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Sequence, Boolean, Text, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .image import Image
from .blogtag import Tag

class Blogpost(Base):
    """Post model."""

    __tablename__ = 'post'

    post_id_seq = Sequence('post_id_seq', metadata=Base.metadata)
    id = Column("id",Integer, post_id_seq,server_default=post_id_seq.next_value(), primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)    
    imageList = relationship(Image, backref="post")
    tagList = relationship(Tag, secondary="posttag")
```

Now , everytime I try to run my `setup.py` which imports both the files, I keep getting this error

```
 File "blogtag.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .blogpost import Blogpost
ImportError: cannot import name 'Blogpost'
```

Can you please let me know what might be happening here please ?

Thanks

Comment: You have a circular import.

Comment: Gagan, please share more details. How's your project folder structure?

Comment: Regardless of the circular import, your problem is a circular dependency. Defining ˋTagˋ requires ˋBlogpostˋ to have been defined already and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of circular import. In general, circular imports are the sign of bad design.

in module `blogpost.py`

```
from .blogtag import Tag
```

You are importing `Tag` class which forces the python interpreter to first load `blogtag` module.

Then in `blogtag.py`

```
from .blogpost import Blogpost
```

which again tells interpreter to load `Blogpost` class first. But interpreter already have been to the blogpost module and `Blogpost` class is yet not loaded into memory. So interpreter says that there is no class `Blogpost` in blogpost.py

To solve this issue, the best solution is to remove mapping statements and create a mapping model for `Tag` and `Blogpost`

module `blogtag.py`

```
from .base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, schema, Sequence, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class Tag(Base):
    """Tag model."""

    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    tag_id_seq = Sequence('tag_id_seq', metadata=Base.metadata)
    id = Column("id",Integer, tag_id_seq,server_default=tag_id_seq.next_value(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
    isactive = Column('isactive', Boolean)
```

module `blogpost.py`

```
from .base import Base
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Sequence, Boolean, Text, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .image import Image


class Blogpost(Base):
    """Post model."""

    __tablename__ = 'post'

    post_id_seq = Sequence('post_id_seq', metadata=Base.metadata)
    id = Column("id",Integer, post_id_seq,server_default=post_id_seq.next_value(), primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)    
    imageList = relationship(Image, backref="post")
```

mapping module `tag_blogpost_mapping.py`

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .base import Base
from .blogtag import Tag
from .blogpost import Blogpost


class BlogpostTagMapping(Base):
    tag = relationship(Tag)
    blogpost = relationship(Blogpost)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do have a follow up question please - where did you get `post_mapping` and `tag_mapping` secondary values in your `tab_blogpost_mapping.py` file from ? I did the same thing and I am getting the following error ```expression 'tag_mapping' failed to locate a name ("name 'tag_mapping' is not defined"). 
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Gagan. `secondary` is  not required in a mapping table so just remove that argument from both the statements and it should work fine. Updated the answer as well